# GKE ingress resource returns 404 although it is connected to a service

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I added a default `nginx-ingress` deployment with a regional IP that I got from GCP.

```sh
helm install nginx-ingress \
             nginx-stable/nginx-ingress \
             --set rbac.create=true \
             --set controller.service.loadBalancerIP="<GCP Regional IP>"
```

I have a dockerized node app with a single .js file. Which I deployed with a basic helm chart. The service is called node-app-blue-helm-chart

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '0.0.0.0';
const port = 80;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    if (req.url == '/another-page'){
        res.statusCode = 200;
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
                res.end('<h1>another page</h1>');

    } else {
        res.statusCode = 200;
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
                res.end('<h1>Hello World</h1>');
    }
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log('Server running at http://%s:%s/', hostname, port);
});

process.on('SIGINT', function() {
    console.log('Caught interrupt signal and will exit');
    process.exit();
});
```

I deployed following ingress resource:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-resource
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "*.example.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: node-app-blue-helm-chart
            port:
              number: 80
```

Although ingress resource acquires IP and endpoint. It still returns 404 error. What can be wrong? Can `host: "*.example.com"` section be a problem?

More info:

```
kubectl describe ing ingress-resource
Name:             ingress-resource
Namespace:        default
Address:          <GCP Regional IP>
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (10.0.0.2:8080)
Rules:
  Host           Path  Backends
  ----           ----  --------
  *.example.com  
                 /*   node-app-blue-helm-chart:80 (10.0.0.15:80)
Annotations:     kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
                 nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: false
Events:          <none>


kubectl describe svc node-app-blue-helm-chart
Name:              node-app-blue-helm-chart
Namespace:         default
Labels:            app.kubernetes.io/instance=node-app-blue
                   app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                   app.kubernetes.io/name=helm-chart
                   app.kubernetes.io/version=1.16.0
                   helm.sh/chart=helm-chart-0.1.0
Annotations:       meta.helm.sh/release-name: node-app-blue
                   meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
Selector:          app.kubernetes.io/instance=node-app-blue,app.kubernetes.io/name=helm-chart
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Families:       <none>
IP:                10.3.248.13
IPs:               10.3.248.13
Port:              http  80/TCP
TargetPort:        80/TCP
Endpoints:         10.0.0.15:80
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

What I tried:

Removing * from /* in ingress resource. Didn't fix the issue.

```
kubectl describe ing ingress-resource
Name:             ingress-resource
Namespace:        default
Address:          W.X.Y.Z
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (10.0.0.2:8080)
Rules:
  Host           Path  Backends
  ----           ----  --------
  *.example.com  
                 /   node-app-blue-helm-chart:80 (10.0.0.15:80)
Annotations:     kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
                 nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: false
Events:
  Type    Reason          Age        From                      Message
  ----    ------          ----       ----                      -------
  Normal  AddedOrUpdated  <invalid>  nginx-ingress-controller  Configuration for default/ingress-resource was added or updated
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to edit your Ingress. You have set a `path=/*`, which may not be what you meant to do. A `/` should do:

```
[...]
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "*.example.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: node-app-blue-helm-chart
            port:
              number: 80
```

Comment: Didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Are you sure, @bcan ? You've left your public IP on the last Ingress describe, FYI. I can query it and get a response from your NodeJS code (`curl --header 'Host: abc.example.com' http://W.X.Y.Z/ping` returns `<h1>Hello World</h1>`). Also works without path. The `/another-page` still sends me to the same "Hello World", maybe that's not the actual path you match in your code, ... AFAIU, your ingress works great.

Comment: Thanks for fixing. But when I try with a browser it only returns 404. Tried with different browsers and private modes etc.

Comment: Testing from my browser (chrome), having forced DNS resolution (/etc/hosts file), I can see the Hello World. Maybe you're using some kind of http proxy, that can't resolve your .example.com name? Do you have any valid DNS name you might use instead? If you do some `host W.X.Y.Z`, you should find the value for the PTR record associated with your IP. You can use that name, in your Ingress configuration, and your browser, ... might work better?

Comment: Changed host to an actual domain I own, now it works.